# Why are computers not cubes?

Tags: computers

If you look at the old NeXT Computer, two things jump out about the form factor: it's a cube, and it looks really cool. Ditto the original Connection Machine.

If you look at, well, absolutely every other computer produced since then, one thing they all have in common without exception is that they are not cubes. Granted that there is no particular technical advantage to being cubical, I would have expected some manufacturers to do it just for the sake of appearance; manufacturers certainly do plenty of other things to make their products look cool.

Is there any technical disadvantage of the cube shape that would account for it being universally shunned?

Comment: Speak for yourself, my computer is a cube.

Comment: Real estate. You want to minimize the footprint to use as little floor or desk space as possible. (Remember: this is the era of flat screens).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I can think of at least two.

The natural construction of a computer is to put as much stuff as possible on the motherboard - a *flat* PCB. You can then have expansion cards sideways (PC-style) plus peripheral disks inside on cables. The "flattish" form factor lends itself to laptops, 1U rackmount systems, and set-top-boxes.

The other reason is heat dissipation. For this you tend to want a high surface-area-to-volume ratio and good laminar airflow through the system. A cube is the opposite of that unless you can make one face a fan. Again, if you look in 1/2/4U cases a surprising amount of space is full of ducting to make this work.

Steve Jobs agreed with you that cubes are cool, which is why he tried to make the PowerMac G4 Cube. It was generally considered to be a cool-looking failure due to heat and expandability problems.

Comment: Apple's latest swing at high density gives up on expandability, and as for cooling, the thing more or less resembles a jet engine.

Answer (score 4):

You asked for technical disadvantages but the overwhelming reason will be the practical disadvantages of cubes.

Cubes are an awkward and wasteful shape to have on a desk or under a desk. And with the vast majority of PCs being used with desks, space efficiency will drive it. (I'm talking about desktops and not laptops, with all the irony that carries.)

Looking cool is great for about ten minutes until it's subsided into irritatingly inconvenient.

Irritation and frustration have a more profound effect on consumers than admiration and pride and manufacturers recognise that.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any technical disadvantage of the cube shape that would
>   account for it being universally shunned?

Well, motherboards are basically flat (certainly not cube like) and if volume occupancy is a measure of how something might intrude into an office or desktop environment, a rectangular shape will be able to fit a larger motherboard.

Also the amount of air it has to shift in and out (via the fan) will be smaller and this will tend to make it easier to cool.